# iOS - get NSDictionary from NSUserDefaults :Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I try to retrieve `NSMutableArray` from `NSUserDefaults` that have been saved.

I store the `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray* mySavedTremps = [[defaults objectForKey:UD_MY_TREMPS] mutableCopy];

if (!mySavedTremps)
        mySavedTremps =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary* trempDict = NSMutableDictionary* trempDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"please", @"help", @"me" @"!", nil]
[trempDict setValue:trempId forKey:@"trempId"];
[mySavedTremps insertObject:trempDict atIndex:0];
[defaults setObject:mySavedTremps forKey:UD_MY_TREMPS];

[defaults synchronize];
```

And try to retrieve the `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray* myTrempsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:UD_MY_TREMPS]];

for (Tremp* tremp in myTrempsArray) {        
        if([tremp.trempId isEqualToString:@"1234"]) {
            [myTrempsArray removeObject:tremp];
            break;
        }
    }
```

But, when I access tremp (param in the for loop) like:

```
tremp.trempId
```

I get this error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
```

The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: can you explain what is this "NSMutableDictionary* trempDict = [tremp trempDict];"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save your `Tremp` object to the defaults, you are actually saving it as a dictionary.

But when you read it out, your code assumes you have an array of `Tremp` objects.

You want something like:

```
for (NSDictionary *trempDict in myTrempsArray) {
    Tremp *tremp = ... // add code here to create a Tremp from the dictionary
    if([tremp.trempId isEqualToString:@"1234"]) {
        [myTrempsArray removeObject:tremp];
        break;
    }
}
```

BTW - this code will crash. You can't modify an array that you are fast-enumerating through. Change the loop to be a standard `for` loop but go through the loop in reverse.

Also, when you save the data, replace the call to `setValue:forKey:` to `setObject:forKey:`.